# Fitting smooth through xyplot

Tags: r, lattice

This question seems simple but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I'm trying to fit a smooth line through longitudinal dataset as illustrated in the following code

```
library(nlme)
xyplot(conc ~ Time, data = Theoph, groups = Subject, type = c("l", "smooth"))
```

The output isn't quite what I'm after and there are multiple warnings. I would like to fit a smooth through the entire data.   As a bonus, if anyone could also show how to do this using ggplot, that would be great.

Comment: Still not clear to me, did you try `xyplot(conc ~ Time, data = Theoph, type = "smooth")`

Comment: @dickoa, thanks. The above code gives a smooth through but I would like to include individual plots for each subject in the plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To plot the individual Subjects as separate lines and points but plot the overall smooth use either of the two lattices approaches shown or the classic graphics and zoo approach at the end.  Also note that we need to order the time points to produce the overall smooth and the nlme package is not used.  Also note that no errors are given by the code in the question -- only warnings.

**1) trellis.focus/trellis.unfocus** We can use trellis.focus/trellis.unfocus to add an overall smooth:

```
library(lattice)

xyplot(conc ~ Time, groups = Subject, data = Theoph, type = "o")

trellis.focus("panel", 1, 1)
o <- order(Theoph$Time)
panel.xyplot(Theoph[o, "Time"], Theoph[o, "conc"], type = "smooth", col = "red", lwd = 3)
trellis.unfocus()
```

**2) panel function** A second way is to define an appropriate panel function:

```
library(lattice)

o <- order(Theoph$Time)

xyplot(conc ~ Time, groups = Subject, data = Theoph[o, ], panel =   
  function(x, y, ..., subscripts, groups) {
     for (lev in levels(groups)) {
         ok <- groups == lev
         panel.xyplot(x[ok], y[ok], type = "o", col = lev)
     }
     panel.xyplot(x, y, type = "smooth", col = "red", lwd = 3)
})
```

Either of these gives the following output.  Note that the overall smooth is the thick red line.

(continued after chart)

[image: screenshot]

**3) zoo/classic graphics**  Here is a solution using the zoo package and classic graphics.

```
library(zoo)

Theoph.z <- read.zoo(Theoph[c("Subject", "Time", "conc")], 
   index = "Time", split = "Subject")

plot(na.approx(Theoph.z), screen = 1, col = 1:nlevels(Theoph$Subject))

o <- order(Theoph$Time)
lo <- loess(conc ~ Time, Theoph[o, ])
lines(fitted(lo) ~ Time, Theoph[o,], lwd = 3, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much!

Comment: One question-Why is the smooth for 1 and 2 slightly different in shape from answer 3? It seems that no. 3 is the best.

Comment: Likely the loess parameter settings are different.  You could change them in xyplot by using `panel.loess` .

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `latticeExtra` package to add a smoother to your first treillis object

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

xyplot(conc ~ Time, data = Theoph, groups = Subject, type = "l") +
  layer(panel.smoother(..., col = "steelblue"))
```

And here is the `ggplot2` version of the same graph

```
ggplot(data = Theoph, aes(Time, conc)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Subject)) +
  geom_smooth(col = "steelblue")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.